# How do i implement google/facebook login to my application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, sails.js, ionic-framework

so i have an application based on the ionic-framework and a server side based sails.js.
my application uses data like username, passwords, user image etc.. so i though i'll be a good idea to use google sign up using OAuth 2.0.
I have no idea how to implement that to my application. could you please give me a wide detailed explanation with some examples on how OAuth 2.0 is working with sails?

Comment: could you get any solution?

Comment: i used sails-generate-auth

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth) ? It is based on [passport](http://passportjs.org/) and it generates whole authentication layer for your sails.js application including OAuth2.0 and OpenID.

**Edit**

More information about accessing third-party user's profile details:
[next step after the oauth authentication - sails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754236/next-step-after-the-oauth-authentication-sails)