# next step after the oauth authentication - sails

Tags: twitter-oauth, sails.js

I have followed [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sails-generate-auth) guide in my sails app and everyone seems to be working perfectly fine.
when clicking the twitter button on `localhost:1337/login` page the website redirects the user to the authentication page. when the user accept the terms, the website redirect the user back to server homepage. here it ends, how can i use the twitter data that twiiter Apparently gave me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user is authenticated in third-party service, he will be redirected back to your website together with his account information.
You can access the profile details in your passport service:

*/api/services/passport.js*

```
passport.connect = function (req, query, profile, next) {

  var user = {
    firstName: profile.name.givenName,
    lastName: profile.name.familyName
  };

  // save passport, user, etc..
}
```

More details about *profile* variable:
[passportjs.org/guide/profile/](http://passportjs.org/guide/profile/)